# A list of topics well-suited for self-answered questions

Tags: discussion, support, self-answer

The idea of self-answers seem to be slightly against the primary purpose of this site. This site doesn't want to accumulate the kind of junk other sites tend to (I think). Also, this site wants to become an encyclopedia of non-trivial, useful information in the form of questions and answers.

But if self-answers are allowed, then the question-answers (might be) more inclined towards being trivial or not useful for a lot of people.

My question is: What kind of self-answered questions must be promoted to be more suitable for this site. What kind of topics? etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The idea of self-answers seem to be slightly against the primary purpose of this site

How so? The primary idea of this site (and the others of the network) is to create a repository of good questions and answers. If a self-answer and its associated question fall into this goal, there isn't a problem.

> But if self-answers are allowed, then the question-answers (might be) more inclined towards being trivial or not useful for a lot of people.

As you say - **might be**. At this point, the onus is on you to show that this is indeed the case. Rather than us preventing *potential* abuse by removing the option (and then just getting people working around the limitation), lets keep the option and deal with consequences if they do arise.

As it stands, we have good results with community moderation - it applies just as well to self-answers. If they are bad, they get downvoted, closed and deleted (as would their associated bad question).

> What kind of self-answered questions must be promoted to be more suitable for this site

I believe I've covered that in the first section.

Comment: I didn't mean for this question to stand as a feature request, that is why I did not include the tag. I just want to know what kind of topics and questions might be more suitable for self-answered questions, so that they are relevant to this site. I just thought such a list might be titled "A list of topics well-suited for self-answered questions".

Comment: Same topics that are suitable for any question. If you can answer your own question and it is a good question and on topic and the answer would be of good quality, it is a suitable question for self-answer.

Comment: In other words - "A list of topics well-suited for self-answered questions on this site" == "A list of topics well-suited for questions on this site".

Comment: And a third attempt - the "self-answer" part has no bearing on the suitability of a question.

Comment: I seemed to think it did. After posting the question, I don't seem to remember why

Comment: You have a hypothesis in your question that such posts may be "more inclined towards being trivial or not useful for a lot of people".

Comment: I am just deleting the question. I no longer make sense to myself (which is usually the point at which I stop an argument).

Answer (score 2):

A self answered question has exactly the same quality standards and expectations as a non-self answered question.  There are no additional requirements of a self answered question, nor are they immune from any of the requirements of other questions.

If you feel that a question isn't useful, or wouldn't be helpful to anyone but the asker, then that is a problem *regardless* of whether or not the question is answered by the question author.

Comment: That is not what I meant. I think that if somebody simply posts a self-answer for the sake of it, it is more likely to be less useful and more trivial, don't you think?

Comment: @Truth-seek It's not *inherently* less useful. Some people will self answer questions that are useful, and some people well self answer questions that aren't useful, just like some people will post non-self answered questions that are useful and some post non-self answered questions that are not useful.  Treat all useful questions the  same, and all not useful questions the same, regardless of what answers there are and who posted them.